# Is there a way to style checkbox appearance in p5js to become a toggle switch?

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, toggle, p5.js

I'm trying to change the appearance of a checkbox in p5 canvas using javascript to have the same appearance as a toggle switch like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

I've tried experimenting in the css file in [this sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/cnatalisa/sketches/eCGWzxJ3q) but it doesn't seem to be working

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```js
let checkbox;

function setup() {
  checkbox = createCheckbox("label", false);
  checkbox.changed(myCheckedEvent);

  createDiv(`
    <label class="switch">
      <input id="toggle" type="checkbox"  />
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>`);

  checkbox = select('#toggle');
}

function myCheckedEvent() {
  if (this.checked()) {
    console.log("Checking!");
  } else {
    console.log("Unchecking!");
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.siwtch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

#toggle:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#toggle:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

#toggle:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please put your code into your question and describe what isn’t working. When I ran your code it showed a switch which toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You're approach basically looks reasonable, it just needs a few tweaks (see comments):

```js
let checkbox;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  // There's no need to use createCheckbox() since you're create the <input /> tag yourself
  // Also I got rid of the wrapping div since it wasn't strictly necessary.
  let label = createElement(
    'label',
    `<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
     <span class="slider round"></span>`
  );
  
  // Because I'm using createElement() to create the label I have to add the class attribute:
  label.addClass('switch');

  checkbox = select('#toggle');
  // Register the event handler after using select() to get the p5.Element for the checkbox.
  checkbox.changed(myCheckedEvent);
}

function myCheckedEvent() {
  if (this.checked()) {
    console.log("Checking!");
  } else {
    console.log("Unchecking!");
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
/* COMMENT: there was a typo here, uses to be .siwtch */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

#toggle:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#toggle:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

#toggle:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions and it works perfectly in p5.js, however when I run it in my project using Atom, why doesn't it seem to work?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the whole project. I would guess it is most likely some conflicting CSS that is affecting how this label/input/span gets displayed. I suggest using you web browser's developer tools to look at the elements and review the computed CSS properties. There is probably some discrepancy there and you can then trace the conflicting setting to the source in our project.